# EventLog selecting source that has not been previously created

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I've been using the following basic code which I took from a website to write messages to the Windows Event Log using the EventLog class from System.Diagnostics

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteEventLogEntry("This is an entry in the event log");
    }

    private static void WriteEventLogEntry(string message)
    {
        // Create an instance of EventLog
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();

        // Check if the event source exists. If not create it.
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("TestApplication"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("TestApplication", "Application");
        }

        // Set the source name for writing log entries.
        eventLog.Source = "TestApplicationNotExisting";

        // Create an event ID to add to the event log
        int eventID = 8;

        // Write an entry to the event log.
        eventLog.WriteEntry(message,
                            System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error,
                            eventID);

        // Close the Event Log
        eventLog.Close();
    }
}
```

I've tweaked the code above so that the Source that is being selected is one that I have not previously created using the CreateEventSource method. I expected this to throw an exception but instead it works perfectly well and I have a message in the Event Log from source "TestApplicationNotExisting".

Why is this not throwing an exception? if I can select sources on the fly then what's the point of the CreateEventSource method?

Comment: Can you use log4net, or NLog? Both do this out of the box, without you having to write this laborious code. Unless you're doing this for personal education...

Comment: I am doing this for personal education :)